# Returning Most Relevant Search Results Using LINQ Where/Take

Tags: c#, linq, list, .net-4.0, where-clause

I have a `List<Locations>` that will be filtered to yield a set of results relevant to a search term.

At the moment, I tried these 'search results' by filtering with the following:

```
return locations.Where(o => o.Name.Contains(term)).Take(10).ToList();
```

**Problem**

If I were to enter 'Chester' as the search term, I will never see the item "Chester" despite it existing in the `locations` list. The reason for this is that there are 10 or more other items in the list that contain the String "Chester" in their name (Manchester, Dorchester etc.).

How can I use LINQ to first of all take the results that start with the search term?

**What I've Got So Far**

```
    var startsWithList = list.Where(o => o.Name.StartsWith(term)).Take(10).ToList();
    var containsList = list.Where(o => o.Name.StartsWith(term) && !startsWithList.Contains(o)).Take(10 - startsWithList.Count).ToList();
    return startsWithList.AddRange(containsList);
```

I don't like the above code at all. I feel like this should be achieved in one `Where` as opposed to performing two Where and Take's and combining the two lists.

Comment: the general way you do something like this is with a scored match, so if value = search score= 1000, if starts with then score = 100, if contains score = 10 if partially contains score = 1 then you sum all the scores and order by the sum before taking your result set, though this is probably more complex than you need

Comment: Sounds like you want something like [approximate string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching), to know which is the best result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just order ascending before Take, putting a lower value for items starting with term.

```
return locations.Where(o => o.Name.Contains(term))
                .OrderBy(m => m.Name.StartsWith(term) ? 0 : 1)
                 //or OrderByDescending(m => m.Name.StartsWith(term))
                .Take(10)
                .ToList();
```

adapted with the improvement of MikeT (exact match before StartsWith), you could just do

```
return locations.Where(o => o.Name.Contains(term))
                    .OrderBy(m => m.Name.StartsWith(term) 
                                     ? (m.Name == term ? 0 : 1) 
                                     : 2)
                    .Take(10)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: This looks nice. Exactly what I was after! +1. I didn't know you could do this with the OrderBy.

Comment: ALso unless you really have to don't do the ToList as this will force the instantiation of the dataset at this point where as otherwise if you do any other queries they will be added to the data query and not run separately on the data, especially important if this is linqToSQL

Answer (score 4):

I have created a [new github project](https://github.com/ninjanye/SearchExtensions) that uses expression trees to search for text in any number of properties

It also has a `RankedSearch()` method which returns the matching items with the number of hits for each record meaning you can do the following:

```
return locations.RankedSearch(term, l => l.Name)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Hits)
                .Take(10)
                .ToList();
```

If you wanted you could search accross **multiple properties**

```
return locations.RankedSearch(term, l => l.Name, l => l.City)
```

... or for **multiple terms**,

```
return locations.RankedSearch(l => l.Name, term, "AnotherTerm" )
```

... or for both **multiple properties** and **multiple terms**

```
return locations.RankedSearch(new[]{term, "AnotherTerm"}, 
                              l => l.Name, 
                              l => l.City)
```

**Checkout this post for more information on the SQL generated and other usages:**
http://jnye.co/Posts/27/searchextensions-multiple-property-search-support-with-ranking-in-c-sharp

You can download this as a nuget package to:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions/

Comment: This looks spot on. I'm very interested, will download it a little later. Thanks very much mate.

Comment: Hi @DeeMac, thanks for your interest.  Feel free to take a look and put forward any suggestions.  Contact me via http://jnye.co or twitter.  All deets are on my [SO profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/611288/ninjanye)

Answer (score 2):

Raphaël's Solution will work but if you were say searching for Warwick you could find that it might not put Warwick the top of the list if Warwickshire is also a possible location,using the scores you can also extend this infinitely with more matching methods, as well as tweaking the score values to refine your search order

```
return locations.Select(l => New {SearchResult=l, 
                                    Score=(L.Name == Term ?
                                        100 :
                                        l.Name.StartsWith(term) ?
                                            10 :
                                            l.Name.Contains(term) ? 
                                                1 : 
                                                0
                                        )})
                .OrderByDescending(r=>r.Score)
                .Take(10)
                .Select(r => r.SearchResult);
```

note i would probably do this by making a Match method and do the logic in there rather than in the linq like i did above so it would just be

```
return locations.OrderByDescending(Match).Take(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

All Solutions will work but the better score can gain more easier as below

```
return locations.Where(o => o.Name.Contains(term))
            .OrderBy(m => m.Name.IndexOf(term))
            .Take(10)
            .ToList();
```

as a result each **name** that contain **term** at nearest to start, show first.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
return locations.Where(o => o.Name.Contains(term))
                .OrderBy(m => m.Length)
                .Take(10)
                .ToList();
```